# localhost:3000 won't update after saving changes in sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I'm new to programming and trying to make changes to a Rails app. I downloaded a forked repo from Github and got it up and running on my local computer after running rake db:migrate (originally got error messages).

I've since made changes to a few HTML files (minor - changed text of a few sentences) in Sublime and saved, but they aren't reflected in browser.

I refreshed the browser and tried restarting the server. I must be missing steps. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What kind of changes did you make?

Comment: I edited a few HTML files (just to test to make sure changes were coming through before I did more).

Comment: One example of not working code would help.

Comment: One example: I tried changing a sentence of copy on the site. I changed the word from "Your" to "You" and saved it in Sublime. When I refreshed in browser, it remained "Your." Another example: I deleted the sentence altogether and saved in Sublime. The sentence still showed in browser. The code is "working" I guess you could say, but changes made in Sublime aren't being reflected in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be happening. Most likely, you are getting some browser cache( but you could be getting  a network, web server cache as well)

Try reloading the page with ctrl + r ( or cmd + r if you don't like real nix)

Next you could try loading in an incognito window  to see if it's a session level issue.

Next you can try restarting your server. In general in development environment there shouldn't a cache set up but maybe you are hitting an issue there.

In my dev config, I have all the caching off. In my dev browser I have all the dns/browser caches disabled.

At the end of the day, you could be modifying the wrong file. Try ack'ing or grepping to see if there are other occurrences of that text in other files. Often there will be multiple header partials or multiple layouts that are similar but not really.

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work, but thank you for the suggestions. I ultimately deleted the fork and re-forked. Now the changes I make are reflected in the browser. Not sure why it didn't work earlier.